# Set position of LabelCell inside SelectBox in Scene2D - LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a **SelectBox**; how do I position the selected item text (label cell) ? For example in a TextButton I used `getLabelCell().padLeft ...` whenever I wanted to reposition the text; what can I use for the SelectBox actor because there is no getLabelCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select_box.background.setLeftWidth(DX_VALUE);
```

modifies the left padding of the text . This works well for me because all text add to the list have approximately the same character length therefore the same width.